# Data frame/list of correlated variables specified above a certain limit

Tags: r, correlation, r-caret

I am creating a correlation matrix, and via the findCorrelation() function from the caret package I am identifying parameters that have a correlation with another parameter higher than 0.75.
After that I am removing the correlated parameters coming out of the findCorrelation command.

```
highlyCorrelated <- findCorrelation(correlationMatrix,cutoff=(0.75),verbose = FALSE)
correlated_var=colnames(data[,highlyCorrelated])
data.dat <- data[!(names(data) %in% c(correlated_var))]
```

For completeness sake, in presenting later results, I want to present a list of what parameters are removed, and also because of what correlation.
Is there a way to generate a data frame that contains in the first column the removed parameter, and in the following columns the parameter(s) that that specific parameter was correlated to?

I can call upon certain correlations by using:

```
correlationMatrix[correlationMatrix[x,]>0.75,x]
```

Where x is an identified parameter with a correlation higher than 0.75 with other parameter(s). But I am not sure how I can turn this into a data frame or table, in order to present the findings.

Help is much appreciated!

Regards,
Eddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got somewhere using the packages plyr and rowr:

```
cor.table <- matrix(, nrow = 0, ncol = 0)
for (i in sort(highlyCorrelated)){
  cor.table.i <- c(paste(colnames(correlationMatrix)[c(i)],":"),paste(names(correlationMatrix[abs(correlationMatrix[i,])>0.75,i])))
  cor.table <- cbind.fill(cor.table,cor.table.i,fill=NA)
}
cor.table <- t(cor.table[c(-1)])
```

It's a bit of a workaround, and maybe not the prettiest, but at least I get something I can export.

I can't get rid of the fact that the answer shows that the parameter is correlated to itself, for some reason.

Comment: I have the same question and my gut feeling is that using verbose=TRUE in findCorrelation could be another approach which will not show the parameters with themselfes but it requires to translate this kind of output into variable names:  Compare row 4  and column  5 with corr  1.851 
  Means:  0.99 vs 0.674 so flagging column 4 
Compare row 5  and column  2 with corr  1.193 
  Means:  0.731 vs 0.54 so flagging column 5